# Use Elisp macro instead of two function arguments?

Tags: functions, elisp-macros, arguments, apply

Is the following sort of shortcut macro possible to implement?

```
(defmacro region-end-beg ()
 "Replacement for '(region-end) (region-begin)' in source code"
 (...))
```

So that

```
(buffer-substring  (region-end-beg))
(setq region-length (- (region-end-beg))
```

Can be used as a shortcut for

```
(buffer-substring  (region-end) (region-beginning))
(setq region-length (- (region-end) (region-beginning))
```

This example is semi-contrived.  What I'm interested in is there is a general technique to make this kind of macro in lisp (particularly elisp).

Comment: There's no way to have a single macro call expand into two expressions.

Comment: I don't think a macro can expand to more than one separate s-expression. You could, with some effort, make a code-walking macro `(with-region-end-beg ...)` that would replaces all occurences of `(region-beg-end)` in the code indicated by `...` with `(region-end) (region-beginning)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. Function `buffer-substring` requires two arguments. Function `-` will accept a single argument, but in that case it just returns the negative of that numeric argument.  What you want to do is, in effect, apply such functions to a *list* of arguments.  You can use higher-order function `apply` to do that.

What you can do, if you want, is have a macro or an ordinary function return a *list* whose elements are the values of `(region-end)` and `(region-beginning)`, using, say, `(list (region-end) (region-beginning))`.

But there's no reason to use a *macro* to do that. As a general rule, use an ordinary function instead of macro, whenever that does what you need.

With the list constructed by your function, you would then use `apply` to apply `buffer-substring` and `-` to the list returned by your function. That applies those functions to the list elements as arguments.

```lisp
(defun region-end-beg ()
  `...`
  (list (region-end) (region-beginning)))

(apply #'buffer-substring (region-end-beg))

(apply #'- (region-end-beg))
```